# Any finite extension of Q is simple extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Any finite extension of Q is simple extension of Q?   Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know how to google for "simple field extension"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Primitive Element Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) says:

> Every finite separable field extension is simple.

Since $\mathbb Q$ has characteristic zero, every  algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$ is separable.